# How to pass a joined table to a view in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, viewmodel

I am building a project in Mvc and having some trouble. I have worked with viewmodels countless times before, and the relationship between Controller-View, but this problem has stumped me.

I am wanting to pass a joined table to the view, and im not sure how to go about this.

this is the code for the query

```
var query1 =
from r in db.Requests
group r by r.RequestNum into rsg
select new 
{
    rsg,
    TechHrsSum = (from rr in rsg select rr.RequestSteps.Select ( rs => rs.Procedure.TechHrs).Sum(h => h)),
    ProcessHrsSum = (from rr in rsg select rr.RequestSteps.Select ( rs => rs.Procedure.ProcessHrs).Sum(h => h))

};
```

I understand this is anonymous, but I cannot understand how to pass the data so it a dynamic and usable in the view. Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't your data layer not build a model of the data, that modeled data should be passed to your View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One really simple idea is to change the model to have "NotMapped" columns for the info from other tables (assuming a 1-to-1 relationship):  So in model:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string myStringVar { get; set; }
```

then in the controller:

```
        ourTableModel.myStringVar  = ""; // default

        if (ourTableModel.ourTableModel_key != null)
        {
            var ourOtherTable = db.otherTable.Find(ourTableModel.ourTableModel_key);
            if (ourOtherTable != null)
            {
                ourTableModel.myStringVar = ourOtherTable.stringInOtherTable;
            }
        }
```

as long as this is an R (Retrieve or Read) operation this is then as easy to display in the view as anything else, conversely there are strategies to save it in the controller if one is doing a CUD operation.

Answer (score 2):

Your options are to create a class object that has properties for the values you to pass to the view.  Or you can put the object in the ViewBag and access the values through that.  I would recommend the first option.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, but your remark may not be accurate.

> ```
>          How to pass a joined table to a Model View Controller View.
> ```

You don't pass a table in that traditional sense, you pass a series of modeled data. The modeled data will represent the data structure retrieved from your database.  That is the whole premise of Model View Controller, to abstract the data in a manner that embodies the *stateless* nature of Hypertext Transfer Protocol.

The simplest approach is to define your model in the context of how it will be utilized not only to your back-end but your user interface as well.

> I've got a Billing object, it requires the following information:
>
> - Person
> - Account
> - Address
> - Total

As you can see the `Billing` object though it is simply defined, our context begins to embody the implementation, thus the true shape begins to be defined.  For simplicity sake, I'll mockup a simple model:

```
// Example Model:
public class Person
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName {get; set; }
}
```

So the premise of a *Person* has been defined, whenever my *View* needs to display a *Person* I'll always need the following defined.

**Important:** With a model defined, we know that our Data Layer will need to populate the *Modeled Data* and our *Business Logic* will work with those entities. For simplicity, a linear approach:

```
// Controller:
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
     // Person Model:
     var model = new Person();

     // Call Database Method, to populate Model
     model = dbPerson.Fill(id); // dbPerson.Fill would be a method to populate.
     return View(model);
}

// View: (Index of our Controller)
@if(Model != null)
{
     foreach(var content in Model)
     {
           <div>@content.FirstName</div>
           <div>@content.LastName</div>
     }
}
```

By declaring the `var` in our *Collection*, the type will be defined at compile time.

That would be how you transfer data.  This basic approach applies to even more complex objects.  Especially since your *Table View* can embody any object so it may be displayed.  Hopefully this clarifies a bit.

I may have misunderstood your intent, but I do believe you're struggling with the overall conceptual notion.  Remember, Model View Controller represents:

[image: MVC Workflow]

Comment: @mason Your correct, it is compile time.  Intellisense defaulted to `runtime` because I used a dynamic type when I hovered over it.  Learned something new, I'll edit.

Comment: @mason Visual Studio 2015 default Intellisense, 2013 works correctly though.